# Take the metric space $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual formula for $d$. Set $E=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:1\le x^2+y^2\le 4\}.$ Show that $E$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Take the metric space $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual formula for $d$. Set $$E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}.$$ Show that $E$ is connected.

Intuitively this is true, but how do I find the parametric equations to prove path-connectedness and thus connectedness?

Answer (score 0):

Any point $p$ in $E$ is on the circle of some radius $1\leq r_p \leq 2$. Same for another point $q$ (on the circle of radius $r_q$). Starting at $p$, one way is to construct a path along the line connecting the origin to $p$ in the direction of the second circle, and then follow the circle of radius $r_q$ until arriving at point $q$.

Answer (score 0):

The polar coordinates $c$ map $(r, \theta) \to (r\cos\theta, r \sin \theta)$ is continuous from $[0,\infty) \times [0,2\pi]$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

$E = c[([1,2] \times [0,2\pi])]$ which is the continuous image of a path-connected set (hence path-connected too).